# How to modify whois contact details?

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

```
function modify(.......)
{
  $mcontact = file_get_contents( "https://test.httpapi.com/api/contacts/modify.json?auth-userid=$uid&auth-password=$pass&contact-id=$cid&name=$name &company=$company&email=$email&address-line-1=$street&city=$city&country=$country&zipcode=$pincode&phone-cc=$countryCodeList[$phc]&phone=$phone" );

  $mdetails = json_decode( $mcontact, true );

  return $mdetails;
}
```

using this modify function, displays warning mesage

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://...@hihfg.com&address-line-1=3,dfgdf,fgdf&city=dfgfd&country=India&zipcode=641005&phone-cc=91&phone=756657) 
  [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
  HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request in /home/gfdgfd/public_html/new_one/customer/account/class.whois.php
  on line 49
```

Please help me, modify contact details..

Comment: I can't accept answers, because i have less than 15 reputation

Comment: That's just wrong. You need 15 rep to *upvote*, not to *accept*. Click the checkmark icon below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request` - everything you need to know: You are sending a request the server doesn't like.

Are you sure it accepts a GET request and doesn't require POST? Is the URL correct?

Comment: I have used this link,try to modify whois contact details....http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/791

Comment: Please read that page carefully: `HTTP Method: POST`. And besides that, start accepting some answers **now**!

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong. You have an additional space character: `&name=$name &company=$company`. Remove it.

Comment: I copied it from your question, make sure you paste exactly the same line as in your code.